# How to pass a variable from laravel 5.4 to vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

Is it possible to pass a variable from controller to vuejs? I have read some answers but nothing seems to work for me. I want to pass the variable $url to vue. I have tried some thing like this

**`var url = {!! $url !!};`** this gives me syntax error: unexpected token in app.js

example url http://eventregistry.org/json/suggestConcepts?prefix=sam&lang=eng&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

**Controller**

```
class SearchCompanyName extends Controller
{
    public function getcompanyname($name)
    {
      return "http://eventregistry.org/json/suggestConcepts?prefix=" . $name . "&lang=eng&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    }   

    public function index()
    {  
       $url = $this->getcompanyname(Input::get("company_name_by_user"));
       return view('searchcompany', ['url' => $url]);

    }
}
```

**vue app.js**

```
Vue.component('search', require('./components/Searchnames.vue'));
const search = new Vue({
    el: '#search',
    data: {
    },
    method: {
        getMessages: function(){
            console.log('I am here')
        }()
    }
});
```

**blade template**

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
{!! $url !!}
 <search></search>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: try addind a props to you search component : like <search :url={!! $url !!}></search> and in your vuejs component, add the props "url" and access the url via this.url.

Comment: what is the syntax error? What does the source of var url = {!! $url !!}; look like on the page?

Comment: syntax error is unexpected token for var url = {!! $url !!}

Comment: adding o props gives also gives an error - invalid expression: :url=http://eventregistry.org/json/suggestConcepts?prefix=sam&lang=eng&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Comment: Adding a prop is the way to go. Read the vue docs about it. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question earlier that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409633/better-way-to-use-laravel-old-and-vue-js/44411312#44411312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare your javascript variable in a script tag within a blade file, you need to put the variable in quotes like so

```
<script>
  var url = '{{ $url }}';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I was thinking how to access this variable in app.js

Comment: @Imi How i achieve this is by defining all php-javascript variables in my main blade file like i showed above and then i reference it in the app.js script. make sure you call the app.js script after you declare the variables.

Comment: Thanks did not know we can do stuff like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package : https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

```
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

Comment: As I totally support this answer, I am unable to get this to work with laravel 5.4 properly. It keeps comming up with 'The use statement with non-compound name 'Javascript' has no effect'