# Form modal binding in laravel with vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have 2 models `Tour.php`

```
public function Itinerary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itinerary', 'tour_id');
}
```

and `Itinerary.php`

```
public function tour() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour', 'tour_id');
}
```

`tours` table:

```
id|title|content
```

`itineraries` table:

```
id|tour_id|day|itinerary
```

In `tour-edit.blade.php` view I have used vue js to create or add and remove input field for `day` and `plan` dynamically.

Code in `tour-create.blade.php`

```
 <div class="row input-margin" id="repeat">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <label >Day:</label>
              <input type="text" name="day[]" 
              class="form-control">            
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              {{ Form::label('itinerary', " Tour itinerary:", ['class' => 'form-label-margin'])}}
              {{ Form::textarea('itinerary[]',null, ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'itinerary']) }}
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="deleteOption(row)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="btn btn-primary add" @click.prevent="addNewOption" >
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Field</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to populate these fields with their respective data. But all data i.e itinerary belonging to a tour are being displayed in `itinerary` textbox in JSON format.[image]

My vue js sript is:

```
<script>
var App = new Vue({
el: '#repeat',
data: {
  day:1 ,
  rows:[
  @foreach ($tour->itinerary as $element)
    {day: '{{$element->day}}', plan: '{{$element->plan}}'},
  @endforeach
  ]
},

methods: {

  addNewOption: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.rows.push({"day": "","itinerary":""});
  },

  deleteOption: function(row) {
    var self = this;
    self.rows.splice(row,1);
  },

}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid mixing blade into JavaScript, instead the best option is to make an ajax call to an api route which returns your data in `json`, which can then be processed by Vue:

```
methods:{
  getItinerary(){
     axios.get('api/itinerary').then(response => {
        this.itinerary = response.data;
     })
  }
}
```

However, with this approach you will likely need to use `vue-router` rather than laravel web routes, which puts us into SPA territory.

If that's not an option (i.e. you still want to use `blade` templates), you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409633/better-way-to-use-laravel-old-and-vue-js/44411312#44411312) I gave the other day which shows you how to init data from your blade templates.

What *you* seem to be doing is using laravel's form model binding to populate your forms, not `Vue`, so your model data is not bound to the view. So, you will need to decide which one you want to use. If it's vue you just want to use a normal form and bind the underlying data to it using `v-model`:

Now any updates in the view will automatically be updated by Vue. I've put together a JSFiddle that assumes you will want to continue using Laravel web routes and blade templates to show you one approach to this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/w6qhLtnh/